# When did spring-driven clocks start being used?

Tags: physics, astronomy, classical-mechanics

On a tour of the Royal Observatory at Greenwich I saw the following display on the history of mechanical clocks:

[image]

[image]

[image]

They suggest that mechanical clocks and astronomy weren’t really combined in England until the 16th century.

Now I thought mechanical clocks [came into use](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock#Early_mechanical) in the 13th century.

My question is: **When did spring-driven clocks start being used?**

Comment: Again ? In the same Wiki's article we can find : "**Spring-driven clocks appeared during the 15th century**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the British Museum we can see one of the first spring driven clocks built in 1450 here:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Spring-driven clocks were invented in 15 century (as pocket clocks). Clocks had no use in astronomy in the beginning (neither weight-driven nor spring-driven) because they were not accurate enough. Accurate clocks require a pendulum or a balance, and these are 17th century inventions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_eggs

Comment: Fantastic answer - any chance of a reference, person or place or year?